# How to make a generic class conform to a protocol for specific type?

Tags: swift, generics, swift4, generic-programming, swift-protocols

Say there exists a generic struct:

```
public struct Matrix<T> where T: FloatingPoint, T: ExpressibleByFloatLiteral {
// some methods...
}
```

Is it possible extend the struct to conform to a protocol for constrained `T` using `where` clauses? E.g. something like

```
extension Matrix where T: SpecificClass : SomeProtocol {
    // This does not compile :(
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, such construct isn't possible (circa Swift 3.1 at least).

For instance:

```
class SomeClass { }
protocol SomeProtocol { }

extension Matrix: SomeProtocol where T == SomeClass { }
```

Gives a very clear error message:

> Extension of type `Matrix` with constraints cannot have an inheritance clause.

---

But all is not lost... as correctly noted by Alexander, there is already a proposal lined up for Swift 4! The feature will be called [Conditional Conformances (SE-0143)](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md).

A nice example for all *[protocol-oriented programming](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/408/)* hackers out there:

```
extension Array: Equatable where Element: Equatable {
   ...
}
```

If an array contains equatable elements than said array is also equatable.

---

**Update**. Swift 4 is out but this feature hasn’t landed yet. We may need to wait until Swift 5 for this...

Comment: This feature is called *Conditional Conformance*, and has been accepted by [the Swift team in proposal 0143](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md), and is to be implemented in phase 1 of Swift 4.

Comment: Not yet implemented in Swift 4 :(